# Redirect URL with a parameter to homepage

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

Recently we have released a new website for a company but some of the old links still apear on google webmaster tools.

I tried to create a redirect with some luck, however I want to fully remove the parameter and redirect all the links matching the structure to the new homepage.

So these pages

```
http://www.example.com/job/view.php?id=142
http://www.example.com/job/view.php?id=3453
http://www.example.com/job/view.php?id=567
```

will redirect to

```
http://www.example.com
```

I used this redirect

```
RedirectMatch 301 /job/view.php$ http://www.example.com/
```

which works OK with the exception that the resulting website looks like:

```
http://www.example.com/?id=142
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this way

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^job/view\.php$ http://www.example.com/? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Hi Justin, I added that rule but it isn't working. :/

Comment: It said page not found.
I changed the www.example.com with my link and tried and the basic 404 page appeared like it was appearing before adding the RedirectMatch rule.

Comment: What's the url you tried ? This code is supposed to redirect `http://domain.com/job/view.php` (with or without query string) to `http://www.example.com`

Comment: Hi Justin, It fixed it, however I was adding it at the end of the htaccess instead at the begining. Thanks

Comment: It seems that it's the question mark at the end of `http://www.example.com/?` that makes the difference; thanks for this.